# Laravel. How to get/pass logged in users ID in Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, laravel

I'm developing a system in Laravel and Backbone.

The user can view their own profile eg, email address, Name, DOB,  etc

In Laravel I am using the Resource Controller (index, create, store, show, edit, update and destroy)

So if the user would like to view their own profile they would go to domain.com/users/{their ID}.

The issue I am having is how do I pass {their ID} to backbone so I can append it to the domain name so when backbone fetches it can fetch their record.

Backbone is working fine. If I hardcode the id in it will grab the correct data.

The user ID is currently stored in the session.

What is the best practice here? How are you suppose to send backbone the User ID.

Backbone Model/profile.js

```
    var Profile = Backbone.Model.extend({   
     urlRoot: domain + "/users",
    initialize: function () {
        this.profile = new ProfileCollection();
    }   
}),

ProfileCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    initialize: function(models, options = {}) {
        this.id = options.id;
    },
    url: function() {
        return domain + "/users/" + this.id;
    }, 
    model: Profile,

});


return {
    Profile: Profile,
    ProfileCollection: ProfileCollection
}
```

Backbone View/profile.js

```
    var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '.page',
    initialize: function() {
        self = this;        
        profile = new Profile.Profile;  
        profileCollection = new Profile.ProfileCollection([], { id: 453445 });
    },


    render: function(){

        profileCollection.fetch({
            success : function(){       
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: How your `Backbone` view is getting included/loaded, how you are connected from server side ?

Comment: I'm using requireJS. I've striped that out of the example.

Comment: How you show the page from the server side ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your view (`Laravel View`) do something like this:

```
@if(Auth::check())
    <script>
        var userID = "{{ Auth::user()->id }}";
    </script>
@endif
```

Now you can use the `userID` in your `JavaScript`. You may also create a [View Composer](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers):

```
// You may keep this code in your filters.php file
View::composer('layouts.master', function($view) {
    $user = null;
    if(Auth::check()) {
        $user = Auth::user()->toJson();
    }
    $view->with('userJs', $user);
});
```

In your `master` layout, between `<head>`:

```
<script>var userObj = {{ $userJs or 'undefined' }}</script>
```

So, you can always use the user object in js:

```
if(userObj) {
    console.log(userObj.id);
    console.log(userObj.username);
    console.log(userObj.email); // all properties
}
```

### Update:

You can omit the `toJson()` from `$user = Auth::user()->toJson();`. `Laravel` will do it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked (The first one). Is this the correct way to do it? Is it best practice?

Comment: @user742736, Yes, this is correct and the second one will be automatically injected in your `<head>` tag depending on the log in state and it's better, IMO.

Comment: Where do I put the view:Composer?

Comment: @user742736, I've updated the answer about the placing, you may put it in your  `filters.php` file.