# How to print angularJS var inside PHP

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write a php url parameter as a function of angularJS

```
<span ng-click="update([[a.code]], $ index, '{{route (' article_update', array (' id '=> [[a.code]]))}}')>Update</ span>
```

And do not get it. 
How could I?

**Note: I use interpolation '{{' to '[[' for angular, because conflict with blade template**

Comment: I don't know php. So can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve there in more detail?

Comment: [Check this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214469/laravel-how-to-get-pass-logged-in-users-id-in-backbone/22215067#22215067) and [this article is also related](http://heera.it/laravel-pass-user-object-javascript-object).

Comment: I created a [simple voting application](http://angularcode.com/voting-system-similar-to-stackoverflow-using-angularjs-php-and-mysql/) using angularjs,php and mysql. Hope this app will provide you a clear picture about ng-click